# Why "object is not defined" error not getting thrown in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, try-catch, undefined-behavior

Without a `try-catch`, the below snippet throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: myObj is not defined`

```js
try {
  if (myObj !== null && typeof myObj !== "undefined");
} catch (e) {
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = e.Message;
}
```

```html
<p>The error is
  <mark id='error'></mark>
  <p>
```

Why is the error message not getting printed inside `<mark id='error'></mark>`?

Comment: Where is it defined?

Comment: @void Yes, it is not defined. This code shall print error message.

Comment: One pointer. undefined is itself an object. So you should use `myObj !== undefined`

Comment: the `mark` element with `id='error'` is probably not defined at the time the code is run - is the javascript before the markup in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `e.message`, you were getting `undefined` because `e` does not hold a property name `Message`.

```js
try {
  if (myObj !== null && typeof myObj !== "undefined");
} catch (e) {
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = e.message;
  //  or you can use e directly as well.
}
```

```html
<p>The error is
  <mark id='error'></mark>
  <p>
```

Comment: @student ignore that, was just trying out something. Edited.

Comment: Was unable to decide amongst the best answer. Your answer included more information than required.

Comment: Any suggestion why [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/dLzmzyrd/) is not printing values please?

Comment: no, I'm talking about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/dLzmzyrd/) fiddle. No error!

Answer (score 3):

just remove the Message attribute from the exception object, just e itself sufficient.

```
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = e;
```

this will work

Answer (score 2):

The message in e.Message is lower case:

```js
try {
  if (myObj !== null && typeof myObj !== "undefined");
} catch (e) {
  document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = e.message;
}
```

```html
<p>The error is
  <mark id='error'></mark>
  <p>
```